# Is there a way to check if std::random_device is in fact random?

Tags: c++, c++11, random

Quoting from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random):

> std::random_device is a non-deterministic random number engine, although implementations are allowed to implement std::random_device using a pseudo-random number engine if there is no support for non-deterministic random number generation.

Is there a way to check whether current implementation uses PRNG instead of RNG (and then say exit with an error) and if not, why not?

Note that little bit of googling shows that at least MinGW implements `std::random_device` in this way, and thus this is real danger if `std::random_device` is to be used.

---edit---
Also, if the answer is no and someone could give some insight as to why there is no such function/trait/*something* I would be quite interested.

Comment: Real danger? You shouldn't be using `<random>` for cryptographic applications, ever. If there's a real danger, use a dedicated and auditable solution.

Comment: `std::random_device is a non-deterministic random number engine, except when it isn't.`

Comment: Have a look at the "Dieharder" random number test suit http://www.phy.duke.edu/~rgb/General/dieharder.php Note: it needs over 2GB of random data to perform its test.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is there a way to check whether current implementation uses PRNG instead of RNG (and then say exit with an error) and if not, why not?

There is a way: [`std::random_device::entropy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device/entropy) will return `0.0` if it is implemented in terms of a random number engine (that is, it's deterministic).

From the standard:

> ```
> double entropy() const noexcept;
> ```
>
> *Returns:* If the implementation employs a random number engine, returns `0.0`. Otherwise, returns an entropy estimate for the random numbers returned by `operator()`, in the range `min()` to `log_2(max() + 1)`.

Comment: According to the standard you are fully right.  However, I read on cpprefeference.com that *"This function is not fully implemented in some standard libraries. For example, gcc and clang always return zero even though the device is non-deterministic. In comparison, Visual C++ always returns 32, and boost.random returns 10."*

Comment: @Christophe I think technically GCC and clang are not wrong to do that. The only requirement is that a PRNG will return 0, but a RNG could return 0 simply because the standard only defines "entropy estimate" in a footnote. At least they are just pessimistic. However, VC++ and boost.random being overly optimistic is a bit worrying.

Comment: However, said pessimism also precludes this method from differentiating between RNG and PRNG based implementation, making it rather unhelpful. Also VC++ could be realistic, but to check that would probably require a lot of insider knowledge about Windows.

Comment: @Xarn Yes, it means you should be pessimistic about the library as a whole, which is probably true.

Comment: @JosephMansfield yes these libraries are using the principle of prudence. So you have to assume the worst case.  But I had the impression that OP wanted an objective way to find out if it's PRNG or real RNG

Comment: Even assuming the estimate is reasonably accurate, and the function is implemented correctly, there is no way to tell entropy which is permanently zero (i.e. a PRNG) from entropy which is zero just now (i.e. an RNG that happens to have spent all its entropy).

Answer (score 0):

There is no 100% safe way to determine real randomness for sure.  With a black box approach the best you could do do is to show evidence if it's not fully random:

- first you could verify that the distribution seems random,  by generating a lot of random munmbers and making statistics about their distribution (e.g.  generate 1 million random numbers between 0 and 1000).  If it appears that some numbers come out significantly more often than other, then obviously it's not really random.
- THe next you can is to run several time a programme generating random numbers after the same initial seed.  If you obtain the same sequence of random numbers then it's definitively PRNG and not real randmness.  However, if you don't obtain the same sequence it does not proove tanything:  the library could use some kind of auto-seed (using clock ticks or something else) to hide/improve the pseudo-randmness.
- If your application highly depends on randomness quality (e.g. cryptographic quality) you should consider some more tests, such as those recommended by [NIST SP 800-22](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-22-rev1a/SP800-22rev1a.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Xarn stated above:

*However, said pessimism also precludes this method from differentiating between RNG and PRNG based implementation, making it rather unhelpful. Also VC++ could be realistic, but to check that would probably require a lot of insider knowledge about Windows.*

If you debug into the Windows implementation, then you will find that you end up in RtlGenRandom, which is one of the better sources of cryptographically random bytes. If you debug into the Linux implementation, then you should end up reading from dev/urandom, which is also OK. The fact that they don't tell us that we're not using something awful, like rand, is annoying.

PS - you don't have to have internal Windows knowledge, you just need to attach the symbols to the debugger.